# dask dataframe groupby resulting in one partition memory issue

Tags: group-by, dask, dask-distributed

I am reading in 64 compressed csv files (probably 70-80 GB) into one dask data frame then run groupby with aggregations.

The job never completed because appereantly the groupby creates a data frame with only one partition.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826722/dask-groupby-without-combining-partitions) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826722/dask-groupby-without-combining-partitions) already addressed this issue but focusing on the computational graph and not the memory issue you run into, when your resulting data frame is too large.

I tried a workaround with repartioning but the job still wont complete.

What am I doing wrong, will I have to use map_partition? This is very confusing as I expect Dask will take care of partitioning everything even after aggregation operations.

```
    from dask.distributed import Client, progress
    client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit='8GB',diagnostics_port=5000)
    client

    dask.config.set(scheduler='processes')
    dB3 = dd.read_csv("boden/expansion*.csv",  # read in parallel
                 blocksize=None, # 64 files
                 sep=',',
                 compression='gzip'
    )

    aggs = {
      'boden': ['count','min']
    }
    dBSelect=dB3.groupby(['lng','lat']).agg(aggs).repartition(npartitions=64) 
    dBSelect=dBSelect.reset_index()
    dBSelect.columns=['lng','lat','bodenCount','boden']
    dBSelect=dBSelect.drop('bodenCount',axis=1)
    with ProgressBar(dt=30): dBSelect.compute().to_parquet('boden/final/boden_final.parq',compression=None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most groupby aggregation outputs are small and fit easily in one partition.  Clearly this is not the case in your situation.

To resolve this you should use the `split_out=` parameter to your groupby aggregation to request a certain number of output partitions.

```
df.groupby(['x', 'y', 'z']).mean(split_out=10)
```

Note that using `split_out=` will significantly increase the size of the task graph (it has to mildly shuffle/sort your data ahead of time) and so may increase scheduling overhead.

Comment: thanks @MRocklin  - my workaround was using map_partition and apply function to aggregate - however, I am not sure if this would really cleanly do it correctly